# Android Facebook SDK - newPlacesSearchRequest does not return place field

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Why does the method below not return 'picture' field ?

```
Request.newPlacesSearchRequest( Session.getActiveSession(), 
                    location, 
                    SEARCH_RADIUS_METERS, 
                    SEARCH_RESULT_LIMIT, 
                    null, 
                    new Request.GraphPlaceListCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(List<GraphPlace> places, Response response) {
                            for (GraphPlace place: places) {
                                Log.i(Utils.TAG, place.getInnerJSONObject().toString());
                        }   
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
```

Is there any way to retrieve this field ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code just transforms GraphPlace object into string within the for loop, you did not try to retrieve any field in GraphPlace object.

Moreover the GraphPlace class does not contain any field named "picture" but it contains only four fields:
name, id, category and Location

You can also find this clear using [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) or [GraphPlace documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/interface/GraphPlace/) in Facebook Android SDK

Comment: Thank you. But there is a field called 'picture' in places search. You can confirm it by executing this query: "graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=LAT,LON&fields=id,name,picture,location". I am retrieving this field through manual http request, but I would like to use Facebook SDK Request class and avoid manual management of session.